# Creating TIFF from Contour Lines

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, contour, terrain

I need to quickly create a TIFF terrain (shades of grey terrain) from contour lines, or rather to create a GeoTIFF. In the past, I extracted vertexes from the contour lines and used that to create new contour polygons and used that to create TIFF. But this takes a lot of time and a lot of steps.

Is there a way to do this quickly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use v.surf.rst

An immediate solution which comes to mind is using  `v.surf.rst`, which is a GRASS module accessible via the `Processing'->`Toolbox`

It takes the vector contour layer as input (you will neet to choose the file, as it does not look into currently loaded layers), and produces an interpolated raster, with the desired pixel size.

https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.surf.rst.html

[image]

### TIN Interpolation

Another viable option is `TIN Interpolation`, also accessible via the `Processing'->`Toolbox`.

In this case, Iw ould suggest the "linear" option:

[image]

Comment: Second solution works like a charm. Thanks, mate! I cannot use GRASS as there seems to be a localization issue. Unfortunate. I am glad there are other ways. Thanks again, you made my day.